# How to add a textbox in views filter criteria

Tags: 7, views

There is a view in my site that has filter criteria. I need to add an extra textbox in views filter criteria then based on its value, remove some of the results.

This textbox is not in any of the fields of the view. The [views_php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module add a PHP field to both the fields and the filter criteria, but it doesn't create a textbox in filter criteria.

How can I do that?

Comment: I would strongly advise against using views php, can you give us more context on what values you need in each filter and how they relate to each other?

Comment: There is a content type that has a `field collection` field. I need to have a filter on both the Host Entity title and also one of the fields of the `field collection`. To do so, I created a view of field collection then using ` Host Entity ID` field I can fetch the parent of the field. Unfortunately I can't have both of these values at same time in a view

Comment: I think you need to create a view based on the content type and then in the views relationship panel add a relationship to the field collection you need then you should have access to both the content type fields and the field collection fields.

Comment: @DanielHarper you are right, using relationships and the current view I solved the problem. I can't believe I missed such simple thing. Thanks you very much